# Name of Websites / Stores (Groups) / Store Views

Tags: multistore, store-view

Is the Name field for the websites, stores, store views displayed anywhere that is customer facing? We have a site that has historically always been a single Website store. We are in the process of adding an additional store, and would like to change the 'Name' of the originals so that they make more sense / are more consistent with the names which feel appropriate for the new Website. This will hopefully help make things easier to understand for the admins.

Presumably one of the Names is used in the default store switcher (which we don't actually have in our design), but before going ahead and changing this, is anybody aware of anywhere else this might be echo'd out, or possibly included in the subject / body of a transactional e-mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for the store switcher it shouldn't be shown anywhere. For frontend purposes usually the `System > Configuration > General > Store Name` is used.

However 3th party extensions might use it somewhere so it might be smart to change the store view `name` to something appropriate. The name shouldn't be used anywhere in the code so you should be ok to change it.

Comment: I came across the Store View name, which appears to be displayed to the customer on the account dashboard when they successfully register.

Comment: Ahh you're right. Too bad they use it instead of the normal Store name value.